# having difficulties with js concatenation on rails

Tags: javascript, jquery, ruby-on-rails, concatenation

This is my html and to my understanding im asking the browser to display all my projects and then putting a slider that will be listened by js

```
    <div class='nav_bar'>#</div>
<% if @projects %>
    <% @projects.each do |project| %>
        <li><div class='container'><h1><%=project.name %> </h1>
            <ul>
                <%= form_for project do %>
                <%= fields_for :palette, project.palette do |palette| %>
                <input type="range" id="slider<%=@project.id%>" min="1" max="255" >
                <div id="output<%=@project.id%>"> </div>

                  <%= palette.label 'background_dark_color' %>:
                  <%= palette.text_field :background_dark_color, placeholder: '@palette.background_dark_color' %><br/>

                  <%= palette.label 'background_light_color' %>:
                  <%= palette.text_field :background_light_color, placeholder: "@palette.background_light_color" %><br/>

                  <%= palette.label 'dark_color1' %>:
                  <%= palette.text_field :dark_color1, placeholder: "@palette.dark_color1" %><br/>

                  <%= palette.label 'dark_color2' %>:
                  <%= palette.text_field :dark_color2, placeholder: "@palette.dark_color2" %><br/>

                  <%= palette.label 'light_color1' %>:
                  <%= palette.text_field :light_color1, placeholder: "@palette.light_color1" %><br/>

                  <%= palette.label 'light_color2' %>:
                  <%= palette.text_field :light_color2, placeholder: "@palette.light_color2" %><br/>

                  <%= palette.submit %>

                  <%= link_to 'Destroy',  project,  method: :delete, data: { confirm: 'Are you sure?' } %>

                <% end %>
                </div>
            </ul>

        <% end %></li>
    <%end%>
<%end%>
<div class='circle'><%= link_to "+", new_project_path %></div>
<button type="button"><%= link_to "+", new_project_path %></button>
```

and this is the js for the slider in question

```
window.addEventListener("load", function(){
     var slider = document.getElementById("slider<%=@project.id%>");
     slider.addEventListener("change", function(){
         document.getElementById("output<%=@project.id%>").innerHTML = "value : " + this.value;
    });
});
```

I have 2 theories but no solution, my first theory is I am not concatenating properly (this is js.erb)

and my second theory is that since it is on window load, when it asks for the id's they are not there, what could I possibly do ? :/

Comment: Please update your question to indicate what you want to happen as well as what is actually happening so that we can understand your intention.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You won't be able to retrieve class instance variables in js.erb unless you use [gon](https://github.com/gazay/gon) gem.

Alternatively (and easier) you can just assign the value of @project.id to a divs data attribute and then use the js to retrieve that

```
<div data-project-id="<%= @project.id %>"></div>

var projectId = $('[data-project-id]').data('projectId');

window.addEventListener("load", function(){
  var slider = document.getElementById("slider"+projectId);
  slider.addEventListener("change", function(){
    document.getElementById("output"projectId).innerHTML = "value : " + this.value;
  });
});
```